# ¿Cómo hacer que select 2 de jquery aparezca antes sin cargar el combobox normal al recargar la página?

Tags: jquery, select2

No sé por qué cuando recargo la página me muestra primero el combobox normal y hasta después el select2, no sé a qué se debe esto y cómo hacer que select2 aparezca sin ver el combobox normal

El código que uso es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#nadults').select2();
    $('#nchilds').select2();
 });
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.seleccion').select2();
   </script>
</head>

Comment: Lo hice alli pero no funciono

Comment: Tambien esta en el head

Comment: <script src="assets/js/select2.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.seleccion').select2();
   </script>
</head>

Comment: ¿Podrías hacer un ejemplo reproducible? Editando tu pregunta en `fragmento JavaScript/HTML/CSS Ctrl-M` o en [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/?html,output)

Comment: No se entiende bien. ¿Quieres que se muestre uno y el otro no o que se muestre uno y luego el otro? Si es lo segundo: `$('#nadults').after('<select id="nchilds"></select>');`
  [Ver la doc de `after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

Comment: No lo que pasa es que al cargar la pagina muestra primero el combobox normal y hasta después de recargado se convierte en select2 y esto no es bueno que lo mire el usuario así

Comment: Cuando son `select` múltiples **[la doc sugiere esto](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)**: `<script type="text/javascript">
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
</script>

<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>` **Observa la parte HTML** y en el jQuery, es mejor seleccionar por la **clase** y no por el id.

Comment: Lo hice por clase pero nada no funciona

Comment: No se si tenga que ver que este usando una plantilla